# Redirect iframe after form submit

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms, iframe, submit

I have created an asp page that contains an iframe.
the iframe contains a form, on form submit I want to redirect the iframe to another page.

I have tried this method:

```
//iframe content:
 <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
       function onformsubmit()
       {
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
            $(top.document).find('#page').attr('src', 'page2.aspx');
        },1000);
       }
   </script>     
 </head>
 <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server" onsubmit="onformsubmit()">
      ...
      <div class="menubar">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"  CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
            &nbsp;
            <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
        </div>
       ...
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

but unfortunately it does not work.
I'm using visual basic serverside; clientside i'm using javascript.

Comment: Think of Crosspage posting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementId('iframe_name').src="http://anothersite.com/";
```

@benVG: Wait... The form is *inside* the iframe and after submit you want that *same iframe* to go to another url? If that's the case then you only need `document.location.url = 'http://someurl.com'`. You don't need a reference to the iframe at all if this is the case.

Comment: is almost the same as what I wrote

Comment: @benVG: You replaced the 'iframe_name' above with the actual Id of your iframe right?

Comment: @benVG: Wait... The form is _inside_ the iframe and after submit you want that _same iframe_ to go to another url? If that's the case then you only need `document.location.url = 'http://someurl.com'`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
setTimeout(function(){document.location.href = "www.google.com";},500);
```

may be it will help you